# How can I take raw input from only one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I want to type input from my keyboard in the PowerShell like this: 1 2 3 4
but if I type it like that, it will show this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iqtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    l.append(int(raw_input()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4'
```

It only works when I enter after each input, thus creating 4 lines instead of 1. How can I take all 4 input just in one line? My code:

```
list=[]
l=list
for i in range(0,n):
    l.append(int(raw_input()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#map):

```
l = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I am reading multiple numbers separated by space
So I am using .split(' ') which will return a list of numbers but of type string.
The next step is to use list comprehension to convert all the numbers in the list "x" into values of type int.

```
x=raw_input().split(' ') 
x=[int(num) for num in x]
print x #python2
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code only answers. While they might be a solution to the issue, other people might find it hard to follow your code. Please add some explanation to your code, what it does and why you did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `split` and `list comprehension`
`

```
nums = [int(n) for n in raw_input().split(' ')]
```